# How do I properly access my SQL Server database with trusted connection?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, localdb

```
Dim connString As String = "Server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Database1.mdf;Trusted_Connection=True"

Dim cnn As New SqlConnection(connString)

cnn.Open()
```

I am using the above code in my program and the connection seems to work but for some reason it says

> Cannot open database "Database1.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'Alex\John'.

I have no clue why it won't let me log in since i set it as trusted. Is there something behind the scenes that I am missing?

Comment: Nope, thanks anyways. Think the other guy was closer with me not linking the server.

Comment: So, you aren't using LocalDB? Are you using SQL Server running as a service on your server named "Alex"?  Are you trying to connect from another PC or the same PC?  Are your PCs members of a domain?

Comment: What is the server authentication method of your server? If it is Windows auth you don't need to pass a user name and password, but the account that your pc uses must exist in the server for you to be able to connect to it. While if it is sql server auth, then you need to pass a user name and password that exist under the Logins node in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting to a `mdf`. That is the database file, you need to connect to a server

`Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;`

[Sql Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/)

Comment: How do I know what the server input is? I have a server named Alex but I haven't been able to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
connectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=Database1.mdf;Data Source=Alex-PC;"

connectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=Database;Data Source=Alex-PC
```

Comment: This makes an assumption that the Database has windows based authorization enabled or whichever database you are making a connection to, you have login privileges.

Comment: I will suggest making a connection to Database instead to making the call to .mdf.